# Reading data using Spring data jpa automatically converting timestamp to current timezone

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table **User** with columns

```
user_id, first_name,last_name, created_time(timestamp)
```

I have a class User Entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="user")
@Entity
public class User {
   @Id
   private Long userId;
   @Column(name="first_name")
   private String firstName;
   @Column(name="last_name")
   private String lastName;
   @Column(name="created_time")
   private Timestamp createdTime;
}
```

I have an interface User Repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends CRUDRepository<User,Long> {
   User findByUserId(Long id);
}
```

The created_time stored in database table is **2020-09-08 15:38:13**  and when i read the object using spring data jpa it returned as "2020-09-08 21:08:13"

How should i ensure that this automatic time zone conversion not to happen?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the problem is that Jackson automatically converts the timestamp values to UTC and then serializes the same.

In order to correct this behavior, you can add following property to your application.properties and specify the same timezone value as is being used by your DB server.

```
spring.jackson.time-zone=Asia/Kolkata
```

Comment: I tried the same with a dummy project and it worked for me. Can you please share the versions of different components involved.

Comment: Mysql 5.7.3,  Spring boot 2.3.0.RELEASE, mysql driver 8.0.20

Answer (score 0):

There is an [article](http://blog.montrosesoftware.com/2016/11/08/dates-and-times-in-java-unexpected-timezone-shift/) that explains this problem and also proposes solutions.

You can also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22235687/9381213) answer.